# Which ASP.NET control to choose

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-controls, asp.net-webcontrol

I am making a web app in which I would like to create my own control. According to [[tutorialspoint]](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_server_controls.htm) there are 5 different types of ASP.NET web controls and I can't decide which to choose.

The control will be responsible for displaying an image downloaded from server and then injecting a js script to client browser. The script will display something on the image. The main problem is that I want to make this control totally standalone and encapsulate the script file in it (in `MyProject`).

[image: screenshot]

As for now, my control inherits from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image` and injecting my script (from control, programmatically, using `ScirptManager`) demands adding the js file to my `WebFormsApp` project (but I dont't want to).

The question is - is it possible to encapsulate the js file in my control project? Should I change the type of control I'm currently using?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398930.aspx

Comment: Went through that - getting a 404 with `[assembly:WebResource("MyProject.my_script.js", "application/x-javascript")]` is it a bad path?

Comment: Use some decompiler to see the actual path of the resource and set it right. I recommend the free DotPeek from Jetbrains.